# How do I compare a deployed copy of code with SVN to determine which changeset the deployed code corresponds to?

Tags: svn

I have deployed code in various testing environments. These deployments were usually done with svn export or by copying the directories (minus .svn) between machines.

These directories should still match with the repository they came from, but I'm not sure which revision they were deployed from. How can I have svn look over a directory and find which revision it matches in the repository?

Answer (score 0):

Nohow in common. Versioned files per se doesn't contain any metadata about current revision of Working Copy (or export-source for exporting from repository).

You have to use more "smart" depoy-process and store required information inside "environments" by hand. It can be:

- output of `svnversion` inside WC-root
- output of `svn info` for WC or repository (have a lot of excessive information)
- processed template of subwcrev or it's linux brother svnrev (doesn't support SVN 1.8+ WCs)

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" answer of course is that this is not really a task to do using SVN "after the fact", in general terms. Which version of code gets deployed should be tracked outside of SVN, and/or in a tag. If you always create a tag when you're ready to deploy, and then deploy from that tag, then you should be able to know where it came from.

If your project is only a very small number of files, however, you may be able to use the svn:keywords feature to insert the last revision number each file changed, into the file itself. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html for use. Note this would NOT scale well if you have more than a handful of files you need to track. It would be better to capture information from the repository when you do a deployment, as suggested in Lazy Badger's answer.